# Shell Sort in C language

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, shellsort

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ShellSort(int A[], int array_size) {

    int i, j, h, v;

    for(h = 1; h = array_size/9; h= 3*h + 1);
    for(; h > 0; h = h/3) {
        for(i=h+1;i=array_size;i++) {
            v=A[i];
            j=i;
            while(i > h && A[j-h] > v) {
                A[j] = A[j-h];
                j -= h;
            }
            A[j]=v;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)   
        printf("%d", A[i]);
}

int main() {
    int i;
    int A[] = {6,1,4,3,2,5};  
    int size = 6;
    ShellSort(A,size);

    return 0;
}
```

Problem in shell sort using C language.
It doesn't print the array as `1 2 3 4 5 6`, i.e. it prints the array as it is.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Your code formatting could be better.  Indent all code between braces.  It will be much easier to understand.

Comment: `for(h=1;h=array_size/9;h=3*h+1);` IF array_size >= 9 THEN Infinite loop ELSE Not executed. in this case `h=array_size/9` then h←0 --> `for(;h>0;h=h/3){` Not executed.

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 1):

Just giving what printf to add to see what happens :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void
ShellSort (int A[], int array_size)
{

  int i, j, h, v;

  for (h = 1; h = array_size / 9; h = 3 * h + 1);

  printf("init : h=%d\n", h);

  for (; h > 0; h = h / 3)
    {
      printf("loop : h=%d\n", h);

      for (i = h + 1; i = array_size; i++)
    {
      v = A[i];
      j = i;
      while (i > h && A[j - h] > v)
        {
          A[j] = A[j - h];
          j -= h;
        }
      A[j] = v;
    }
    }

  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    printf ("%d ", A[i]);

}

int
main ()
{

  int i;
  int A[] = { 6, 1, 4, 3, 2, 5 };
  int size = 6;

  ShellSort (A, size);

  return 0;

}
```

=>

```
init : h=0
6 1 4 3 2 5
```

It does not even enter in sorting loop.

So what is the 'h = array_size / 9' supposed to be a loop test and is an affectation...

Here my version of what i believe you would like to reach :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void
ShellSort (int A[], int array_size)
{

  int gap, i, j, k, v;

  for (i = 1; i < array_size; i = 3 * i + 1)
    {
      gap=i;
    }

  printf("init : gap=%d\n", gap);

  for (; gap > 0; gap = gap / 3)
    {
      printf("loop : gap=%d\n", gap);

      for (i = gap; i < array_size; i++)
    {
      printf("inner loop : i=%d\n", gap);
      v = A[i];
      j = i;
      while (j >= gap && A[j - gap] > v)
        {
          printf("innermost loop : i=%d j=%d gap=%d \n", i,j,gap);
          A[j] = A[j - gap];
          printf("(%d.%d)", j, j - gap);
          j -= gap;

        }
      A[j] = v;
      for (k = 0; k < array_size; k++)
        printf ("%d ", A[k]);
      printf("\n");
    }
    }

  for (k = 0; k < array_size; k++)
    printf ("%d ", A[k]);

}

int
main ()
{

  int i;
  int A[] = { 9, 1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 7, 6, 8 };
  int size = sizeof(A) / sizeof(int);

  ShellSort (A, size);

  return 0;

}
```

final result is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 as expected.